# Assigning Range to Array using "With .. End With"

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Assigning a Range to an Array is pretty simple. Still, I found a case in which VBA behaved unexpectedly. I could not find an answer why that is and so I hope someone can explain to me, why it is not working.

Task: Assign a Range (from an open Workbook) to an Array

***Working Code***

```
Dim vrtTabOEen () as Variant
Dim rngTabOEen as Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Name_AB_Tab_Def_OEen)
    Set rngTabOEen = .Range(Name_Tab_Def_OEen)
    vrtTabOEen = rngTabOEen
End With
```

***Non-Working Code***

```
Dim vrtTabOEen () as Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Name_AB_Tab_Def_OEen)
    vrtTabOEen = .Range(Name_Tab_Def_OEen)
End With
```

Using the non-working code, I'll get error 13: Type mismatch.

***Question***
Why do I have to assign the target range to a variable of type 'range' before creating an array out of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many levels of indirection for the implicit coercion from Variant to Variant array to work, due to the fact that Worksheets returns a generic Object and you didn't specify the value property, which you should **always** do. Either:

```
Dim vrtTabOEen () as Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Name_AB_Tab_Def_OEen)
    vrtTabOEen = .Range(Name_Tab_Def_OEen).Value
End With
```

or:

```
Dim vrtTabOEen as Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Name_AB_Tab_Def_OEen)
    vrtTabOEen = .Range(Name_Tab_Def_OEen)
End With
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks Rory, it worked. Although I did not understand the beginning of your first sentence. "Levels of indirection" as well as "implicit coercion" are not known to me. Will look them up